# Creating a UIView that sticks to bottom of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `grouped UITableView` and I'd like to add a UIButton to the very bottom of my `UITableView`. I'm using Storyboard and a UITableViewController. I'm not quite sure where I need to add code or drag/drop UI Elements. I've tried adding a UIView as the footerview in Storyboard and then adding a button to that view, but this doesn't have the desired effect of always staying on the very bottom of the view, similar to a tabbar. Also, the button should always stay in the forefront, and the UITableView should scroll behind it.

```
// tried this but it didn't work:
self.tablview.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initwithview...]
```

Comment: I cheated when I did mine. I use a normal ViewController, added a table view, made it a little shorter than the entire view and then added a toolbar at the bottom with my button. Simplest way to do it, but it might be frowned upon

Comment: @CaptJak yea basically what I want to do is just add a static button over my UITableView...

Comment: You could use the answer you got now, that is very similar to what I was asking if you wanted. If you want more detailed instructions then I could post an answer.

Comment: @CaptJak I'm mainly wondering whether this is the best solution/best practice...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want your `UIButton` to be at the bottom of the screen regardless of the scroll position of the `UITableView` (i.e., not inside the `UITableView`) then you should probably not use a `UITableViewController` subclass.  Instead, if you use a `UIViewController` subclass, you can simply add a `UITableView` to your root `view` property and add a `UIButton` or some other view (such as a `UIToolbar`, etc) with appropriate layout constraints to place it at the bottom of the screen - or wherever you want it.  This is not really possible with a `UITableViewController` subclass, as the root `view` property is required to be a `UITableView` instance.

Comment: @CaptJak Thanks guys. One question about this method: In StoryBoard I would add the UIViewController, correct? Then I would just add the UITableView (not the UITableViewController) and then hook up this new tableview's delegate and datasource to be the UIViewController? Sorry I'm a little bit new so if you could just elaborate on the exact process I'd go through that would great =)

Comment: @BobYousuk That's the right idea.  You'll also have to implement the appropriate `UITableViewDataSource`/`UITableViewDelegate` methods in your class, which you may or may not have been doing with a `UITableViewController` subclass.

Comment: One reason why you might want to use a UITableViewController is that static table views cannot be used with a UIViewController.

Answer (score 6):

OK, If you want to add the toolbar straight to the UITableViewController, you could follow the instructions in [this tutorial](http://www.aboveground.com/tutorials/adding-a-uitoolbar-on-a-uitableviewcontroller) to create a "fake" footer view.

If you are interested in being quick and easy, follow the answer giver above by @CharlesA, but it would probably look nicer if you used a standard toolbar with a UIBarButtonItem instead of just a Round Rect Button.

If you are using a Navigation Controller, then you can just unhide you toolbar (because the Navigation Controller comes with one already), and add a button to do what you need. Coding would be like this:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Button Name"
                                            style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                           target: self
                                           action: @selector(yourMethod:)];

self.toolbarItems = [ NSArray arrayWithObjects: buttonItem, nil ];
```

IMO the way to do it is create a `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController`. Add a `TableView` to the VC, raise the bottom of the TableView enough to fit a toolbar under there, drag and drop a toolbar, drag and drop a UIBarButtonItem onto it. Control-click from the UIBar button item and create your `IBAction`.

Quick, simple, pretty.

Comment: Also a solid way to go.  It's worth mentioning that this will only work if your view controller is presented in a `UINavigationController` (which most probably are).

Comment: @CharlesA. Yep, I noted that in my answer, about halfway through.

Comment: Thanks @CaptJak. Indeed I was looking for fixing UIToolbar at bottom in UITableViewController. Tried many options.  But, didn't know about already available UINavigationController's toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

There is one way to add views to the bottom of UITableViewController without using a UIViewController subclass.

```
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, footerY, footerWidth, footerHeight)];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:footerView];
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible in UITableViewConroller. Inside the viewDidLoad() function in your UITableViewController class add the following code:

```
    let bottomView = UIView()
    bottomView.backgroundColor = .red // or your color
    bottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 78, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 78) // 78 or your size of view
    navigationController?.view.addSubview(bottomView)
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly, in this way the UIView will cover the table. If you have a long list of items in the table the UIView will hide the last item. Be carefully to define the size.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to provide another solution to the existing ones. You can use a normal `ViewController` for your main view where you want to have the sticky view in it. Then, add a `container view` to the `ViewController` to display the table and add another view which should become the sticky view.

It is now possible to point the `container view` to your `TableViewController` and add constraints to the sticky view to make it stay below the table.

[image: Storyboard in Xcode]

As a result the table won't overlap with the sticky view and the sticky view always stays on the bottom of the screen. Furthermore, this concept does not required any changes in your existing `TableViewController`.

[image: Sticky view live demo]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can add UIButton to stick in bottom (or header) of the view, it doesn't matter if you're using `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController`

## Swift 3

### Create Button:

For `X` and `Y` I apply the entire view size, this will allow me to add margin with `-` the amount I like. Then, just set size and width.

```
let myButton: UIButton = UIButton(CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.size.width - 66, y: self.view.bounds.size.height - 66, width: 50, height: 50))
```

**Note**

> See how the width and height are `66`? Well, you need to add your
>   margin to the height and width of the button. In this case, `50 + 16 = 66`. Also, add you background color and other properties, that way
>   your button is visible.

### Add View to NavigationController

```
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(myButton)
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to do this in Swift 2, 1 or Objective-C.

Comment: If you add a view to `navigationController's view`, it will be visible on all the View Controllers of that navigation Controller

Comment: That's pretty easy to work around, just show/hide it in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDissapear`

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this with a TableViewController in swift 1.2 by doing the following (in case people come across this like I did while looking for swift solution).

Once you have your TableViewController on your storyboard drag a View onto the controller. Set it up as you desire and right-click(or ctrl-click) and drag into the source to create an IBOutlet. Then click and drag the view to the top bar [image: view in top bar]. Change to the source for the TableViewController and you will need to derive UIScrollViewDelegate. You will need to set `tableView.delegate = self` and then you can do the following

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, floatingView.frame.height, 0.0)
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, floatingView.frame.height, 0.0)

        floatingView.frame.origin.y = self.tableView.bounds.origin.y + self.tableView.frame.height - floatingView.frame.height
        floatingView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin
        self.view.addSubview(floatingView)
```

And then

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        floatingView.frame = CGRectMake(self.floatingView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.bounds.origin.y + self.tableView.frame.height - floatingView.frame.height, self.floatingView.frame.size.width, self.floatingView.frame.size.height)
    }
```