# What is the base way to add a view below viewcontroller.view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to insert a view below the viewcontroller.view. My idea is to exchange viewcontroller.view with a tempview at runtime.

In "UIViewController+Ext.m":

```
+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class vc = [UIViewController class];

        SEL originalSEL = @selector(viewDidLoad);
        SEL swizzledSEL = @selector(Easy_viewDidLoad);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(vc, originalSEL);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(vc, swizzledSEL);

        BOOL didAddMethod =
        class_addMethod(vc, originalSEL, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(vc, swizzledSEL, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        }
        else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    }); 
}

- (void)Easy_viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *view = self.view ;

    UIView *tempV = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight())];
    tempV.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
    self.view = tempV ;

    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, NavigationHeight(), ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight()-NavigationHeight());
    [self.view addSubview:view];

    [self Easy_viewDidLoad];
}
```

When I add a UITextField on the view controller, the textfield becomes first responder. But the app is killed and throws this error:

> -[UIView leftDockItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f91bb742d80

1. What is the leftDockItem
2. What is the base way to add a view below viewcontroller.view?

Comment: `leftDockItem` is a property of `UIKeyboardDockView`; so you must be using that somewhere. Are you using a 3rd party library?

Comment: @Koen think you follow, i have no use UIKeyboardDockView and no use 3rd party library , app killed mast because i have change  the viewcontroller.view.

Comment: You don't need to use swizzling to replace a view. Do you know what line is causing the crash?

Comment: but i need a immobile view below the scrollViewController . crash on uikit fondution .  i gress uitextfield need the context , but i thange the controller.view cause the problem.

Comment: I recommend you enable exception breakpoints in Xcode, this will tell you exactly where the crash happens. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: i have publish a demo on [link](https://github.com/chenliangloveyou/test) , you run the demo will see the effect.

Comment: I still don't understand why you are using swizzling for this. You can just add another view during runtime, and use auto layout to position it.

Comment: in UITableViewController . i want add a unmoveview on UITableViewController.view . but unmoveview cann't move when scroll UITableViewController . so i think install a tempview below UITableViewController.view . so i think using swizzling.

Comment: What is "unmoveview" ?

Comment: in UITableViewController ,  [self.view addSubView:unmoveview]; this unmoveview will move when scroll the TableView . but i want the unmoveview fobit move.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176843/creating-a-uiview-that-sticks-to-bottom-of-uitableview

Comment: @Koen this link finish my problem , unnecessary using swizzling . thank you very much .